# TeamCity to serve static HTML page

Tags: teamcity

I am looking for a way to serve a few static HTML pages with TeamCity.
I dont want to set up an apache for that, if not absolutely neccessary.

Does anybody know a simple way (or URL scheme) to access static HTML content. I found the following plugin, but that only inserts snippets of HTML in certain positions on existing pages. No way to include a full page.  [PluginLink for others as help.](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TW/StaticUIExtensions)

Thanks for ideas,
Chris

**Solution:**

- Go to e.g. C:\TeamCity\webapps\ROOT
- Create folder e.g. static
- Place file in it (but extension .jsp even if html)
- Will be served without any problems (on URL/static/test.jsp)

Comment: Just verifying that using a static folder, as suggested above, does solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a Tomcat server, just go on your file system where you installed Teamcity and you should be able to find out where you can park some html that will then be available on the Teamcity urls.