# How to add an icon to a nuget package?

Tags: teamcity, nuget-package

We are hosting our own nuget server through Teamcity. Is there any other way to add an icon to a .nuspec file other than specifying a web url (http://....)?

Or is there a place in Teamcity that these icons could be hosted?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, this is the only option using the iconUrl property - See the [NuSpec Reference](https://docs.nuget.org/create/nuspec-reference)

I would generally choose to host shared images like this on a CDN service rather than TeamCity - CloudFlare provide a free service.

Comment: Helpful reminder: make sure the URL does not require login. I hosted on my company wiki, had to mark the wiki page "public". :)

Comment: Given Icon URL is deprecated, this should not be the accepted answer any more (if its possible to change)

Answer (score 62):

As of [NuGet 5.3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/release-notes/nuget-5.3#summary-whats-new-in-53) you can now use `<icon>` to provide a relative path to your JPEG or PNG icon file located within your package.

```xml
<package>
  <metadata>
    ...
    <icon>images\icon.png</icon>
    ...
  </metadata>
  <files>
    ...
    <file src="..\icon.png" target="images\" />
    ...
  </files>
</package>
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#icon

**`<iconUrl>` is now [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#iconurl).**

Comment: This answer should really be the correct answer now as mentioned iconUrl is deprecated.

Comment: but which schema should be used for this? i get "icon" is not valid element errors when packing nuget's...

Comment: @ChrisWatts, you may need to upgrade your nuget.exe you're using to package.  I had the same issue, but then I grabbed the latest, https://www.nuget.org/downloads.  Also, I had better luck renaming my icon file to "icon.png".

Comment: important safety tip the backslash on @target is necessary or it won't work when  you consume the package.

Comment: We started doing this, but this now forces the icon file into the project when they request the nuget package.  Is there anyway to stop this?

Answer (score 16):

If you have your icon in a GitHub repository, you can locate it on GitHub.com, right click and "Copy image address".  Then place this in your .nuspec.  This worked for me:

```
<iconUrl>https://github.com/tcs1896/SharpChecker/blob/master/SharpChecker/SharpChecker/SharpChecker/Icon.png?raw=true</iconUrl>
```

Comment: Icon url will be deprecated: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets#packageiconurl

Answer (score 6):

The [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets#packageicon) is as following

> PackageIconUrl is deprecated in favor of the PackageIcon property 
>  Starting with NuGet 5.3 and Visual Studio 2019 version 16.3

So the way to do it is to add the following to your `.csproj`

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <PackageIcon>icon.png</PackageIcon>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="YOUR_PATH_TO_ICON\icon.png" Pack="true" PackagePath="\" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can host icons on your TeamCity server, quoting Orn Kristjansson in [TeamCity to serve static HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12351906/teamcity-to-serve-static-html-page):

> It's a Tomcat server, just go on your file system where you installed Teamcity and you should be able to find out where you can park some html that will then be available on the Teamcity urls.

So copy your icons into C:\...\TeamCity\webapps\ROOT\ and the will be served as static files.

Answer (score -2):

I have a work around solution.  I tried successfully on windows 10. It is useful if you have to install your application on the offline PC, without internet.

- step 1:
  add tag  to the content of nuspec file. Something like the following:

  `<metadata>
      <id>....</id>
      ...
      <iconUrl>file://C:\app.ico</iconUrl>
      ...
      <copyright>....</copyright>
  </metadata>`
- step 2: generate the nupkg file from the above nuspec
- step 3: generate the exe file from nupkg file
- step 4: 
  put the app.ico file at location: C:\app.ico . You can choose any location according to `<iconUrl>` in the nuspec file. Almost windows PC have "C" drive disk. So that it is comfortable to install .exe in the other PC if you use "C" drive).
- step 5: run exe file to install application on PC.

========= RESULT =============

At C:\Users\"user_name"\AppData\Local\"app_name"  you can see the app.ico appears on the installed application folder.

I hope it may help you!

Answer (score -3):

You can add file to nuspec content folder and specify link in such manner:
**"file://content/images/icon.ico"** 
You can find more info here: [Packages containing Icon and License](https://web.archive.org/web/20171015080943/https://nuget.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Packages%20Containing%20Icon%20and%20License)

Comment: Have you tried this? The page you refer to looks more like a proposal than an actual documentation. And wouldn't the content files be added to the project you install the package to? You can of course just delete those files afterwards, but still...

Comment: The link is dead. This seems to be the relevant issue in GitHub: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/352